# Postgres: Group by clause with predefined set of values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, left-join, coalesce

I can do a query on the following table:

Table1:

```
id       name           source_url
1        object1        www.google.com
2        object2        www.facebook.com
3        object3        www.twitter.com
4        object5        www.google.com
```

Query:

```
select count(*) as counts, source_url from Table1 group by source_url
```

The above query will give me following result:

```
counts    source_url
2         www.google.com
1         www.facebook.com
1         www.twitter.com
```

Now in the above scenario what I want is to group the table1 by my set of elements that I have in an array.
Example

```
arr[] = ["www.facebook.com","www.google.com","www.instagram.com","www.yahoo.com","www.abc.com"]
```

The result I want for the above table should be:

```
counts    source_url
2         www.google.com
1         www.facebook.com
0         www.instagram.com
0         www.yahoo.com
0         www.abc.com
```

Comment: Is that a regular PostgreSQl array or a JSON array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unnest the array to a derived table, left join to it and use `COALESCE()` to replace NULL with 0:

```
SELECT COALESCE(counts, 0) AS counts, source_url
FROM   unnest('{www.facebook.com,www.google.com,www.instagram.com
               ,www.yahoo.com,www.abc.com}'::text[]) source_url
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT count(*) AS counts, source_url
   FROM   Table1
   GROUP  BY source_url
   ) USING (source_url);
```

`source_url` becomes the table *and* column name of the the derived table with this short syntax. You can be more verbose if you need to:

```
...
FROM   unnest(your_array) AS tbl_alias(column_alias)
...
```

Comment: Erwin : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034036/postgresql-sql-view-complex-structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply IN operator with your dataset in your existing query.

```
select count(*) as counts, source_url from Table1 WHERE source_url IN ('www.facebook.com','www.google.com','www.instagram.com','www.yahoo.com','www.abc.com') group by source_url
```

EDIT 2 :
If you need count for those rows which doesn't match your dataset then you can try built in SQL functions. I have mentioned one of them.
Based on your database you can find available functions.

```
select COALESCE(count(*), 0) as counts, source_url from Table1 WHERE source_url IN ('www.facebook.com','www.google.com','www.instagram.com','www.yahoo.com','www.abc.com') group by source_url
UNION
select COALESCE(count(*), 0) as counts, source_url from Table1 WHERE source_url NOT IN ('www.facebook.com','www.google.com','www.instagram.com','www.yahoo.com','www.abc.com') group by source_url
```

Comment: I already tried the above query. It won't give the result for the source_url that is not present in the table. It just gives the count for source_url that is available in the table

Comment: queried the updated answer in my database... It still gives the same result. Do not give the result for url's that have 0 occurrence

Comment: @SyedAsadAbbasZaidi in that case you need do UNION of results. Because you have a condition to be met and also want result set which don't meet the condition. I have add UNION solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select source_url, count(id)
from (
    select * from unnest(arr) as source_url
) as t2
left join lateral (
    select source_url, id from Table1 where source_url = any(arr)
) as t1
using(source_url) group by source_url;
```