# Postgresql Query to split the array into rows

Tags: postgresql

I am running a query which is creating a view for me with following details

```
id      name       brand_id
1        E1          {3,4}
2        E2          {5,7,8}
3        E4          {1}
```

I want to split the records for brand_id into equal number of rows. Hence the above view should look like:

```
id      name       brand_id
1        E1          {3}
1        E1          {4}
2        E2          {5}
2        E2          {7}
2        E2          {8}
3        E4          {1}
```

Over here the brand_id is calculated from a subquery by matching the creation date of record with the date of brand

SQL Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW %I AS 
    SELECT row_number() over(),
    id,
    name,              
    (select array(select id
                  from brand b
                  where status = true and (i.creation_date = b.creation_date)
                  order by b asc) ) as brand_id
  FROM events i
  group by id order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably:

```
CREATE VIEW some_name AS
    SELECT i.id, i.name, b.id AS brand_id
    FROM events i
    JOIN brand b USING (creation_date)
    WHERE b.status
    ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Did you miss `b.status=true` ?

Comment: @wingedpanther `status` is obviously a `boolean` so just the column name suffices. The `WHERE` clause needs an expression that evaluates to a boolean, a boolean column will do just fine.

Comment: I did not know that, How embarrassing !!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, unnest(brand_id) from events;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to extract data.

```
select id  
      ,name 
      ,'{'||replace(replace(regexp_split_to_table(brand_id, E','),'}',''),'{','')||'}'  
from umang.t_st_ques  
order by 1,2,3;
```